# Prove by definition of limits that a given limit is $+\infty$.

Tags: sequences-and-series

need a help with solving this limit, to be more precise with inequation.

$$\lim\limits_{n\to+\infty}\frac{n^2-2n}{n+1}=+\infty$$

Inequation is $(a_n > K)$. It applies for all $K\in\mathbb R^+$.

The end result should be

[image]

thx, do not have a clue how I can obtain this result, maybe there is some adjustment I forgot.

Comment: Its unclear what youre asking. Do you need help with the limit? What is this inequation youre talking about?

Comment: Basically with limit itself but that inequation is (an >h). I have tried some adjustments but ended in deadend, didnt find a solution for (n0).

Comment: How is $a_n$ defined? Where does $n_0$ come from?

Comment: (an) is in assignment its that (nˇ2 - 2n)/(n+1)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Recall that by definition we are looking for

$$\frac{n^2-2n}{n+1}> K \implies  n^2-(2+K)n-K>0$$

that is

$$n>\frac{2+K+\sqrt{(2+K)^2+4K}}{2}$$

or as an alternative

$$\frac{n^2-2n}{n+1}=\frac{n(n+1)-3n}{n+1}=n-3\frac{n}{n+1}>K \implies n>K+3\frac{n}{n+1}$$

and since $\frac{n}{n+1}<1$ it suffices to assume $n_0=[K+4]$.

Answer (score 0):

Rewrite as
$$
\frac{n^2-2n}{n+1} = \frac{n - 2}{1 + \frac 1n}
$$

Now $\frac 1n \to 0$ when $ n \to \infty$ so $1 + \frac 1n \to 1$ when $n \to \infty$
and $n-2 \to \infty$ when $n \to \infty$, this implies

$$
\frac{n^2-2n}{n+1} = \frac{n - 2}{1 + \frac 1n} \to \infty \text{ when } n \to \infty
$$

Or by definition.

Take any $h \in \mathbb{R}$ and set $f(n) = \frac{n^2-2n}{n+1}$ then $f'(n) = 1 - \frac{3}{(n+1)^2} > 0 \ \forall n > 0$ which implies that $f$ is increasing. Thus, we can find $N$ such that $f(N) > h$ for any $h\in \mathbb{R}$

Comment: its cool, but I need to prove that by definiton